# Comparing data from multiple datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will try to explain my issue as best I can but let me know if more details are needed.

I am querying a group of IDs which fit a specific criteria and I want to compare it to another. So, for example, I have 50 IDs for spring 2013, 39 IDs for summer 2013, and 53 IDs for fall 2013. I want to be able to compare each list with the list that comes after it and output the IDs (or just a number) of the people who are in both.

I am able to do this right now by specifying in the where clause the exact lists to compare but I would like to be able to have it run over many years comparing one list with the one that comes after.

EDIT:

Sample data (right now I can just pull 2 lists at a time to compare them):

```
SPRING2013IDS | SUMMER2013IDS | FALL2013IDS | SPRING2014IDS
01            | 01            | 01          | 01
02            | 02            | 04          | 02
03            | 04            | 05          | 03
04            | 05            | 08          | 08
05            | 08            | 10          | 09
06            | 10            | 12          | 12
07            | 11            | 13          | 13
08            | 12            | 14          | 14
```

I want to compare the lists and have an ouput of:

```
Spring2013toSummer2013 | Summer2013toFall2013
01                     | 01
02                     | 04
04                     | 05
05                     | 08
08                     | 10
                       | 12
```

and so on...
I really don't even need the ID numbers in the final outcome (an amount would be fine) because what I'm going to do is just calculate the percentage of IDs that continued from one to the next but I figured I can do that on my own once I get the process flowing better.

Comment: I'm quite sure what you're trying to do... share your datasets or examples of them and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please show some sample input and output to clarify your question.

Comment: I added some more information to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding your existing code to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
create table #MyData (
    Year    smallint    not null,
    Season  tinyint     not null,
    ID      char(2)     not null
    );

insert #MyData
values
    (2013, 1, 'aa'),
    (2013, 1, 'bb'),
    (2013, 1, 'cc'),

    (2013, 2, 'aa'),
    (2013, 2, 'bb'),
    (2013, 2, 'dd'),

    (2013, 3, 'aa'),
    (2013, 3, 'bb'),
    (2013, 3, 'dd'),
    (2013, 3, 'ff'),

    (2013, 4, 'aa'),
    (2013, 4, 'bb'),
    (2013, 4, 'dd'),
    (2013, 4, 'ff');

;with KeyGroup as
(
    select
        (d.Year * 10) + d.Season as SelectKey,
        Year,
        Season,
        d.ID
    from #MyData as d
)
, RankedID as
(
    select
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by sk.SelectKey) as rnk,
        Year,
        Season,
        sk.ID
    from KeyGroup as sk
)
select
    one.Year,
    one.Season,
    one.ID
from RankedID as one
inner join RankedID as following
    on following.ID = one.ID
    and following.rnk = one.rnk + 1;
```

Let me explain.  You asked for each year & season compared to the following one.  The first task is to produce a value where 'following' is easy to determine.  Integers are good for this because `+1` will give you the following integer.  The RankedID `CTE` will give the desired grouping; KeyGroup makes the `DENSE_RANK()` function easy and using a tinyint for the Season makes KeyGroup easy.  Season-as-integer can easily be obtained from season-as-text using a `CASE` statement.

For bonus points you can add `COUNT(1)` to the final `SELECT` list and

```
group by grouping sets (
    (one.Year, one.Season, one.ID),
    (one.Year, one.Season));
```

to the end of the query to get a count of the number of differences *and* the list of IDs.